# Proving that $p \mid a,b,c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Let $p$ be a prime such that $6\mid p-1$, $p \mid a+b+c$ and $p \mid a^4 + b^4 + c^4.$ Prove that $p \mid a,b,c$.

My progress is proving that $a^2 \equiv bc \pmod p$ and its permutations. But I am not sure how to use that $p \equiv 1 \pmod 6.$

Comment: Could you please share from which contest this problem was given. Thank you.

Comment: @SoumyadipDas This was given to me by someone, I have no clue which contest is it from.

Comment: @KriteshDhakal One use of the condition $6|p-1$ might be that the cardinality of the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$ is $p-1$, i.e., if you can show, for example, that $a^3$ or, perhaps, $a^6$ is congruent to something, then $1\equiv a^{p-1}$ is congruent to $\text{something}^{(p-1)/3}$, or, $\text{something}^{(p-1)/6}$. But I am not sure if this will help.

Comment: @ShyamalSayak that was my intuition as well. Basically I proved that $a^3 \equiv b^3 \equiv c^3 \equiv abc.$ I did misread the problem too (should be $6 \mid p+1$ and that did cost me my time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem has a mistake since there's a simple counter-example with $p = 7$, $a = 1$, $b = 2$ and $c = 4$. We have $a + b + c = 7$ so $7 \mid a + b + c$, plus $2^4 \equiv 16 \equiv 2 \pmod{7}$ and $4^4 \equiv 256 \equiv 4 \pmod{7}$, so $a^4 + b^4 + c^4 \equiv 1 + 2 + 4 \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$. However, $7$ doesn't divide any of $a$, $b$ or $c$. Instead, I suspect the condition was intended to be that $6 \mid p \color{red}{+} 1$, i.e., your "$-$" should be "$+$". Assuming this, we then have $p \mid a,b,c$.

From $p \mid a + b + c$, by squaring twice and rearranging, and using that $b^4 + c^4 \equiv -a^4 \pmod{p}$, with the below all being modulo $p$, we get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
a & \equiv -b - c \\
a^2 & \equiv b^2 + 2bc + c^2 \\
a^2 - 2bc & \equiv b^2 + c^2 \\
a^4 - 4a^2bc + 4b^2c^2 & \equiv b^4 + 2b^2c^2 + c^4 \\
2a^4 - 4a^2bc + 2b^2c^2 & \equiv 0 \\
2(a^2 - bc)^2 & \equiv 0 \pmod{p}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Thus, we have what you've already stated, along with the various permutations (due to the symmetry), i.e., that

$$a^2 \equiv bc \pmod{p}, \;\; b^2 \equiv ac \pmod{p}, \;\; c^2 \equiv ab \pmod{p} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Multiplying both sides of the first congruence equation by $a$, the second one by $b$ and the third one by $c$ gives

$$a^3 \equiv b^3 \equiv c^3 \equiv abc \pmod{p} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Next, note the above equation shows that if $p$ divides any one of $a$, $b$ or $c$, it must divide all of them. Assume $p$ divides none of them. Then, by [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), we have

$$a^{p-1} \equiv b^{p-1} \equiv c^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p} \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

The requirement that $6 \mid p + 1$ means that $p - 1 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, so $p - 1 = 3j + 1$ for some positive integer $j$. Thus, from \eqref{eq3A}, \eqref{eq4A} and the problem condition that $a + b + c \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, we then get, modulo $p$,

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
1 + 1 + 1 & \equiv a^{p-1} + b^{p-1} + c^{p-1} \\
3 & \equiv a^{3j+1} + b^{3j+1} + c^{3j+1} \\
3 & \equiv a^{3j+1} + (b^3)^{j}(b) + (c^3)^{j}(c) \\
3 & \equiv a^{3j}(a) + a^{3j}(b) + a^{3j}(c) \\
3 & \equiv a^{3j}(a + b + c) \\
3 & \equiv 0 \pmod{p}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

This is, of course, not possible since $p \neq 3$. Thus, the assumption that none of $a$, $b$ and $c$ are divisible by $p$ must be incorrect, i.e., they are actually all divisible by $p$.

Comment: Ahh so thats what i was missing. Thanks!

Comment: Yup, actually I tried the Fermat's Theorem but me misreading $p+1$ as $p-1$ didn't help (otherwise I'm certain I would've gotten it). Thank you for typing out your solution!

Comment: @KriteshDhakal Once again, you're welcome. I was trying quite a few things, without making any progress due to the incorrect sign being used, before I decided to successfully try a basic counter-example. When I determined what made sense to use instead, then the rest was relatively simple, as you seem to have already determined yourself from your work. Congratulations on almost getting the solution yourself, with just a simple misreading keeping you from getting the answer.